# How can I get this page layout (header and main text)?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

This is what I need (for my thesis's bibliography):

- page number: up right corner, 1.25 cm to the top, and 2 cm to the right.
- main text: 4 cm to the left, 2 cm to the right.

Both the header and the main text should use Times New Roman, 12pt.

At the moment, I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

scroll down~~.
\cite{r1}
\cite{r2}
\cite{r3}
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhead[C]{\sffamily\fontsize{29pt}{29pt}\selectfont%%\thepage} % I tried to change the size of the word but failed
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{75}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}
\bibliography{mybibfile, IEEEabrv}
\end{document}
```

Hi again, I finally solve it by this code, the size, font of the page number is not changed, but it looks OK compared with the other parts of my thesis:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage{lipsum}     % generate paragraph randomly
\usepackage{geometry}   % manipulate the margins of the main text
\usepackage{titlesec}   % manipulate the header/footer


\newpagestyle{main}{            
    \sethead{}{}{\thepage}  % \thepage gives the page number
    \setfoot{}{}{}          % {left}{mid}{right}
    %\headrule              % underline for the header
    %\footrule              % underline for the foot

}

\geometry{left=4cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}  % set the page margin
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
scroll down~~.
\cite{r1}
\cite{r2}
\cite{r3}

\newpage
\pagestyle{main}    %use the main style that has just been defined

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{68}  % the bibliography has its page number starts with 68

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}
\bibliography{mybibfile, IEEEabrv}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[right = 2cm, left = 4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%  Times New Roman-----------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%----------------------------------------
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.507874in}
%  The standard margin is 1 in from the top 1 - .507874in = 1.25cm                  
\fancyhead[RH]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To have the the header be 1.25cm from the top, we need to be `.49...in` down or a `\topmargin` of `-.507874in`.

---

If you use the option `top = 1.25cm` from the `geometry` package, your document will look like (the image below).  I imagine this is an undesirable outcome.

[image]

Comment: What about `geometry` option `top=1.25cm`?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek try it out and see what happens.

Comment: @dustin Hi, thank you, the best explanation always comes with images.

Answer (score 2):

This is a refinement of [dustin's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129105/16967):

- Package `geometry` is also used for the top and bottom margins. Also the layout of the header is set.
- Paper size is probably `a4paper`. It must be specified, because the default for `article` is `letterpaper`.
- Package `fancyhdr` sets a `\strut` that increases the need for `\headheight` to `\baselineskip`. The `\strut` uses `.7\baselineskip` for the height and `.3\baselineskip` for the depth. Therefore `fancyhdr` warns:

  ```
  Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
   Make it at least 14.49998pt.
   We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
   This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
  ```

  Therefore `headheight` is set to `\baselineskip`.
- The height of the page number is a little smaller than `.7\baselineskip`. Therefore the height is calculated and stored in the register `\thepageheight`.
  And the top margin is decreased a little bit to compensate that the top margin is equal to `1.25cm`.
- The other document uses `2.5cm` for the top margin and bottom margin to the text body. Thus we calculate `\headsep` as `2.5cm` minus top margin minus head height.
- The first base line of the text body starts with distance `\topskip`. LaTeX wants to align the base lines of the first lines of the pages. For English texts without accented letters, `\topskip` can be decreased to the height of the uppercase letters (the example uses `\thepageheight`).
- Option `showframe` of package `geometry` shows the page layout. It is also enabled for the image below.
- If package `pagegrid` is added, then it prints a grid with unit `mm` (can be changed) from the top (blue) and the bottom (red). This allows to verify that the margins are set correctly.

Example file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\newlength\thepageheight
\settoheight\thepageheight{1234567890}
\usepackage[
  showframe, % shows the layout of the page
  includehead,
  left=4cm,
  right=2cm,
  top=\dimexpr1.25cm-.7\baselineskip+\thepageheight\relax,
  bottom=2.5cm,
  headheight=\baselineskip,
  headsep=\dimexpr2.5cm-1.25cm-\baselineskip\relax,
]{geometry}
\setlength{\topskip}{\thepageheight}
% \usepackage{pagegrid}% draws a grid on the paper

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rhead{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: should have a system to mark more than one answers. 'cause your post gives what I want too.